# Why am I not getting the index value of a matrix using the which function?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of thousands of coordinate values. And all I want is to find the index of a chosen value. I use this:

```
which(long == -118.1123, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

But I don't get any value. All I get is blank row and column. However, when I do this, I get values.

```
which(long < -118.1123, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

I know this value exists because I have manually checked in the Rstudio pane as well as printed out the value using long[1,2] etc.

dput(long) doesn't work with matrices. Hope you can help.

**Diagnosis as per comments**

```
 - long[1,1] 
[1] -118.0981
 - long[1,1]==-118.0981
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Are you sure the value you see are the value which are stored in the matrix? You can check this with `dput`.

Comment: Very likely this is yet another instance of the R-FAQ "Why aren't these two numbers the same". The print representation of decimal numbers is seldom exact but the "==" test is exact. Learn to use `all.equal`

Comment: My guess is that the value in the Matrix is not really -118.1123. If you know the row and column, check if `long[r,c]==-118.1123` is `T` or `F`.

Comment: @BondedDust Can you please give an example using all.equal? all the answers I have found in SO are using which..

Comment: I have added a diagnosis. Please check question...

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in which(all.equal(long, -118.0981), arr.ind = TRUE) : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical

Answer (score 2):

Your numerical value in the matrix may not be exactly equal to -118.1123. It may contain several digits that aren't displayed since the machine's accuracy is much higher and a perfect identity may not be obtained due to minimal roundoff errors.

I suggest that you try

```
which(signif(long,7) == -118.1123, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Here's a simple example illustrating the problem:

Let's first fill a vector with random numbers between 0 and 1:

```
 v <- runif(100)
```

Then we redefine an arbitrary element of the vector, say element 42, and set it equal to pi:

```
 v[42] <- pi
> v[42]
#[1] 3.141593
```

However, if we test for equality using "==" the result is FALSE:

```
 > v[42] == 3.141593
 #[1] FALSE
```

But if we only consider the first seven significant digits, the position 42 can be extracted from the vector:

```
> which(signif(v,7) == 3.141593, arr.ind = T)
#[1] 42
```

Now, to address your comment, let's assume that you're trying to find the number that is closest to 3.141591 among all your elements in the vector v. We can be certain that this will be element 42, but `R` should find out. This result can be obtained with

```
> order(abs(v-3.141591))[1]
#[1] 42
```

Comment: It works. Could you please check the comment in the other answer?

Comment: Thank you. So when I am doing this: rev(order(lat-30.138892))[1] I get this value: 1965313. but when I reverse check using lat[1965313] , i get this value: 57.76478. Anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, I have a matrix, as mentioned in the question. Does that help?

Comment: Try order(abs(lat-30.138892))[1] i.e., without the `rev()` but with an `abs()` instead.

Comment: This should give you the correct index `idx`of the matrix `m`, but it will be necessary to convert it into row and column number, e.g. with
`row <- idx%%nrow(m) ; column <- ceiling(idx/nrow(m))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using a test that allows a "fuzz-factor" difference to be ignored:

```
> M <- matrix(rnorm(10) , 5,2)
> M
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.2382021  2.1698010
[2,] -1.1617644 -1.1513516
[3,]  1.3597808  0.9365208
[4,]  0.7460694 -1.7216410
[5,] -0.2413117 -0.1780468
> which(M==-0.2382021, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
> which(abs(M - -0.2382021) < 0.0000001, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
```

My comment suggesting `all.equal` didn't work with a matrix argument inside `which`. I checked with @RHertel's choice of `signif` and it does succeed.

```
> which(signif(M,7) == -0.2382021, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks. One problem. I basically want to find an index that is closest to a lat-long value if the exact value doesn't occur in the dataframe. So, when I put lat=30.138892. This returns me a blank, but I want the nearest value. How can I put this logic in? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you can either use the lat and long values separately to find the nearest intersections on your grid (and I answered a question yesterday that asked about finding the nearest times to a set of reference times that could be adapted easily) or you can probably find one of the spatial functions that will do this (although it's not a specialty of mine and I wouldn't know the right function off the top of my head.)